# ¿Cómo insertar un nodo de una lista mediante una QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una lista enlazada que represento mediante una `QTableView`. ¿Cómo hacer para insertar un nodo en medio de la lista?

Hasta ahora lo estoy haciendo mediante lo que entiendo que es un artificio. Inserto un nodo sin información de forma que ya tengo una línea en blanco. Luego edito la línea para darle el contenido que quiero a ese nodo en blanco. Sin embargo esto me ocasiona otros problemas, como el hecho de tener que borrar ese nodo cuando cierro o cambio la vista.

Mirando en internet, he visto soluciones basadas en añadir una línea más que elementos haya que mostrar, y rellenarla con `QVariant()` y otras basadas en el uso de un `QAbstractProxyModel`, pero no sé si hay alguna solución mejor o cual de ellas, sería la más idónea para mi caso.

**Aclaro mejor lo que deseo hacer:**

Básicamente se trata de permitir que en cualquier punto de la tabla y mediante la pulsación de una tecla u orden con el botón derecho del ratón se me inserte una línea vacía, pero sin tener que modificar la fuente de datos. (ahora lo hago insertando un nodo vacío). Entonces, solamente si relleno la primera celda de la fila vacía, donde hay un campo Id, el nodo quedaría creado e insertado en su posición, modificando la fuente de datos, pero si finalmente no se hace nada o se rellenan celdas de la tabla que no son la primera, el nodo no se consideraría y no habría efectos.
Como la tabla es algo más compleja y a golpe de click se pasa a otra zona de la misma, quiero evitar que si finalmente la línea no es editada correctamente (no está rellenado el campo Id) y por tanto, no hay una inserción efectiva del nodo, no tenga que estar borrando ese nodo vacío "auxiliar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, finalmente he hecho un ejemplo sencillo de lo que pretendo que parece funcionar.
Al modelo le añado dos variables:

```
int lineavacia;
bool haylineavacia;
```

Estas variables me sirven para saber si tengo una fila vacía en la tabla y su posición.
Cuando empiezo, por ejemplo, pongo esto en el constructor del modelo:

```
lineavacia = 0;
haylineavacia = true;
```

De forma que aunque mi lista enlazada está vacía, tengo una fila para poder empezar a introducir datos.
La variable haylineavacia modifican el comportamiento de rowCount()

```
int MiModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    int numlineas;
    if (MiLista.isEmpty())
    {
        numlineas=0;
    }
    else
    {
        numlineas = MiLista.size();
    }
    if (haylineavacia)
    {
        return numlineas+1;
    }
    else
    {
        return numlineas;
    }
```

De forma que la tabla me muestra una línea más que los nodos de la lista.
Ahora, para mostrar los datos, he de tener en cuenta tanto la variable **haylineavacia** como **lineavacia**

```
 if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
        {
            if (haylineavacia)
            {
                if (index.row()<lineavacia)
                {
                    return MiLista.at(index.row()).LeeNombre();
                }
                else if (index.row()==lineavacia)
                {
                    return QVariant();
                }
                else
                {
                    return MiLista.at(index.row()-1).LeeNombre();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return MiLista.at(index.row()).LeeNombre();
            }
        }
```

Simplemente le estoy diciendo que si hay una línea vacía, cuando el index sea menor que la posición de dicha línea vacía, retorne los datos tal cual (la posición de la fila coincide con la del nodo). Cuando el index sea la fila vacía me retorne un QVariant(), de forma que se quede en blanco esa línea, y para las posteriores, he de tener en cuenta que cada fila de la tabla le corresponde un nodo una unidad menor que la posición de dicha fila. (Para la fila 5 le correspondería el nodo 4, por ejemplo. Sólo está permitido insertar una fila vacía). Si no hay linea vacía simplemente retorna cada nodo coincidiendo con su posición en la tabla.

La función insertRows() quedaría como sigue:

```
bool MiModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row+count-1);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        //MiLista.insert(row+1,Lista());<--antigua forma de hacerlo
        haylineavacia=true;
        lineavacia = row;        
    }
    endInsertRows();   
    return true;
}
```

Y por último, si añado un dato en la fila vacía, se crea el nodo en la fuente de datos:

```
if (index.column() ==0 && index.row()==lineavacia && haylineavacia)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Creando nuevo nodo";
        MiLista.insert(index.row(),Lista());//ahora es cuando crea el nuevo nodo para acto seguido editar el campo Id y darle el nombre
        haylineavacia=false;
    }
```

Al terminar de crear el nodo esa línea ya no está vacía por lo que la variable *haylineavacia* pasará a **false**.

Bueno, a falta de controlar algunos detalles, de esta forma funcionaría la tabla tal y como deseo.

Answer (score 1):

Los widgets `Q[X]View` se basan en el uso de modelos para gestionar la estructura de los datos a mostrar. Por ese motivo a tu widget le estarás alimentando de datos desde un modelo con un código como el siguiente:

```
view->setModel(model);
```

Ignoro si ese modelo es uno tuyo propio o si te estás basando en el que hay por defecto `QStandarItemModel`. Si es uno personalizado tendrás que implementar el mecanismo de inserción, esto es, tienes que implementar el método:

```
bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent);
```

¿Como se implementa este método?

No hay un código exacto, ya que depende de cómo tengas almacenada la información, pero básicamente consiste en localizar el vector de datos que cuelga de `parent` y añadir donde proceda el nuevo elemento.

Eso sí, para que el modelo sepa que se han producido cambios en los datos hay que llamar a las operaciones `beginInsertRows()` y `endInsertRows()`.

```
bool MiModelo::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
  beginInsertRows(parent,row,row+count);

  // Logica para insertar "count" filas a partir del indice "row" en el padre "parent"
  // Si "parent" es un QModelIndex no valido entonces los elementos se insertan en el primer nivel
  // piensa que los modelos pueden soportar arboles

  endInsertRows();

  return true; // Si la insercion se ha realizado con exito
}
```

Si utilizas el modelo estándar esto te lo ahorras, ya está implementado.

Bien, ahora lo que te falta es añadir la fila al modelo. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es conseguir el `QModelIndex` del padre. Normalmente las inserciones se hacen después de seleccionar o el nodo padre o bien el nodo anterior/posterior... A partir de esa selección puedes obtener el nodo que te interesa.

Bien, con esa información simplemente realizas la llamada:

```
model->insertRow(posicion_fila,modelo desempate);
```

Y la nueva fila aparecerá en la vista.

Para rellenarla puedes usar

```
model->setData(modelIndexDeLaCelda,[VALOR],Qt::EditRole);
```

Un ejemplo que trabaja sobre `QStandardItemModel` (haciendo uso de las funciones genéricas):

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel;
model->setColumnCount(2);

view->setModel(model);

// Se inserta la primera fila
model->insertRows(0,1); // La fila se crea en el primer nivel, no tiene padre
model->setData(model->index(0,0),"A");
model->setData(model->index(0,1),"B");
```

Y el mismo ejemplo haciendo uso de las funciones propias de `QStandardItemModel`

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel;
model->setColumnCount(2);

view->setModel(model);

QList<QStandardItem*> items;
items << new QStandardItem("A") << new QStandardItem("B");

model->insertRow(0,items);
```

Para más información lo ideal es echar un vistazo a los ejemplos de Qt (accesibles directamente desde QtCreator) y a la documentación de Qt:

- [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html)
- [Documentación](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) de Qt sobre su sistema Modelo/Vista

Comment: Hola eferion, he editado mi pregunta para aclarar mejor lo que busco. En otras ocasiones y en otros lugares me has ayudado más que mucho y toda esta parte ya la tengo dominada gracias a ti.

Comment: @user3733164 No te compliques la vida. Eso es mejor comprobarlo a la hora de guardar los datos... revisas tu vector de datos y descartas aquellos elementos que estén vacíos. También puedes hacer que el propio modelo no actualice el vector de datos hasta que la fila no tenga información válida... entonces al recuperar los datos, éstos vendrán sin filas vacías.

Comment: @user3733164 Los proxys sirven para cubrir otro tipo de necesidades (como el filtrado y el ordenado). Intentar simular esa funcionalidad con proxys significa meterte en una selva llena de seres dispuestos a despellejarte lenta y dolorosamente. Creo que me entiendes

Comment: Hola eferion, en tu primer comentario dices "También puedes hacer que el propio modelo no actualice el vector de datos hasta que la fila no tenga información válida". Creo que ese es el comportamiento que busco, me gusta más que el hecho de crear y borrar nodos auxiliares. Pero no sé muy bien cómo crear una línea vacía sin tocar el modelo.

Comment: @user3733164 Piensa que el modelo es el que tiene el control. Con la lógica adecuada es posible hacer que no actualice tu vector de datos hasta que la línea en cuestión no tenga datos... pero hay que implementar esa lógica en el modelo.